# Getting node value in xml column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please let me know why the following XML query is not fetching any result.
I am trying to get value EffectiveUserName tag.

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
        SET @MyXML = '<PropertyList xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <Catalog>name</Catalog>
      <Timeout>600</Timeout>
      <Format>Native</Format>
      <DbpropMsmdFlattened2>false</DbpropMsmdFlattened2>
      <Cube>Model</Cube>
      <DbpropMsmdOptimizeResponse>1</DbpropMsmdOptimizeResponse>
      <DbpropMsmdActivityID>68A6900B-20F8-4A02-AEC3-7C56B2D3C5D5</DbpropMsmdActivityID>
      <DbpropMsmdRequestID>A0D1E07F-AE29-4CCA-AEE4-3B79D97CA426</DbpropMsmdRequestID>
      <DbpropMsmdCurrentActivityID>68A6900B-20F8-4A02-AEC3-7C56B2D3C5D5</DbpropMsmdCurrentActivityID>
      <LocaleIdentifier>1033</LocaleIdentifier>
      <EffectiveUserName>userid@domainname.com</EffectiveUserName>
      <sspropinitappname>PowerBI</sspropinitappname>
    </PropertyList>'


    select  @MyXML.value('(/PropertyList/EffectiveUserName)[1]','varchar(max)')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your XML has a *default namespace* that you must respect and include in your query!

```
<PropertyList xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis"  
              ***********************************************
              xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Use this code to grab the value you're looking for by defining the *default* XML namespace for your query:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis')
SELECT
    @MyXML.value('(/PropertyList/EffectiveUserName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

Comment: select  @MyXML.value('(/*:PropertyList/*:EffectiveUserName)[1]','varchar(max)')

Comment: @ShivaKumar you obviously followed Aducci's advice to use a wildcard for the namespace. That's OK, but you should be aware, that being as specific as possilbe is better. And please allow me one hint: If one of the answers solves your problem, please tick the acceptance check below the answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the namespace by using `*:` before the tag names:

```
select  @MyXML.value('(/*:PropertyList/*:EffectiveUserName)[1]','varchar(max)')
```

Comment: Although this works it is something one should not suggest as general hint. In general with XML it is best (fastest and most secure), to be as specific as possible...